# Russian spelled by a German

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, language

> Hi!
>
> What goes down must come up.
>
> Russian spelled by a German.
>
> Found in a pair of megacities.
>
> Live once!

What am I describing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HeIIo, is it

> **yo** you're looking for.

Hi!

> Yo, is a slang greeting similar to hi.

What goes down must come up.

> When a yo-yo goes down, hopefully it will come up.

Russian spelled by a German.

> Yo, written [ё](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo_(Cyrillic)), the 7th letter of the Russian alphabet, looks German with the diacritic on top of e.

Found in a pair of megacities.

> Found in the Tok**yo**-**Yo**kohama metropolitan area.

Live once!

> **YO**LO - you only live once.

Comment: Well done! I'm baffled by the German line, but I guess it is just because of how it looks like with its diacritic. Having said that, the letter's lookalike is more frequent in French than in German, where it doesn't occur at all.

Comment: Thanks M Oehm, your description is certainly better as more to do with spelling. (Missing credit again!)

Comment: Don't worry about not giving credit. It was just a minor observarion. If I didn't want you to use it, I shouldn't have posted the comment.

Comment: Why the 7th letter, ah it is called yo. Might want to clarify that without having to look at the link.

Comment: I think you're right hkBst - added now.

Comment: right, German has the Umlaut diacritics only on a, o, and u. Never on e :)
most would not know what it is supposed to mean. Dutch are used to see ё when they need to distinguish long ie from i-e, much like the french trema.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I was thinking that German was the language most readily associated with umlauts, but maybe that should have been worded better to take advantage of the fact that there's an identical-looking letter used in many languages.

Comment: For the megacities I was thinking rot13[Arj Lbex] in addition to your answer, btw :)

Comment: [Hёavy Metäl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut) is the country most associated with umlauts. `:)`

Comment: @jafe, in Russian it does not have the same purpose. Umlaut in German has its function to make front vowel from back vowel. In Russian е and ё are not the same. They are just e and yo.

Comment: @rus9384 I know.